Turris Omnia (Knot resolver): t.co does not resolve. twitter.com does
My Turris Omnia cannot resolve t.co, but has no problems with other domains such as twitter.com or x.co. Local names (hpdisk.lan) also work:
root@turris:~# ping t.co
ping: t.co: Name does not resolve

root@turris:~# ping twitter.com
PING twitter.com (104.244.42.193) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 104.244.42.193 (104.244.42.193): icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=11.5 ms

tange@turris:~$ ping x.co
PING x.co (148.72.51.157) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 157.51.72.148.host.secureserver.net (148.72.51.157): icmp_seq=1 ttl=42 time=139 ms

tange@turris:~$ ping hpdisk.lan
PING hpdisk.lan (192.168.1.30) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.30 (192.168.1.30): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.374 ms

The router has no problem querying the auth name servers, so it is not caused by some network filtering or routing problem:
root@turris:/tmp/log# dig @a.r06.twtrdns.net. t.co

; <<>> DiG 9.18.24 <<>> @a.r06.twtrdns.net. t.co
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 13597
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 8, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;t.co.                          IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
t.co.                   300     IN      A       104.244.42.197

Looking up u.co causes this traffic (and pretty similar for [a-s,u-z].co):
14:36:00.469554 IP 100.100.246.190.51757 > 156.154.105.25.53: 20216% [1au] A? U.CO. (33)
14:36:00.484396 IP 156.154.105.25.53 > 100.100.246.190.51757: 20216- 0/6/1 (639)
14:36:00.485495 IP 100.100.246.190.55245 > 193.108.91.245.53: 25634% [1au] A? Ns50.DoMAInCoNtROL.COm. (51)
14:36:00.500380 IP 193.108.91.245.53 > 100.100.246.190.55245: 25634*- 1/0/1 A 173.201.72.25 (67)
14:36:00.500659 IP 100.100.246.190.60650 > 173.201.72.25.53: 49104% [1au] A? U.Co. (33)
14:36:00.513975 IP 173.201.72.25.53 > 100.100.246.190.60650: 49104*- 2/2/1 A 15.197.142.173, A 3.33.152.147 (120)

Looking up t.co causes no traffic. It smells as if Knot Resolver thinks it is auth for t.co
I have tried rebooting the router. This did not fix the issue.
root@turris:~# uname -a
Linux turris 5.15.148 #0 SMP Tue Apr 2 01:04:13 2024 armv7l GNU/Linux
root@turris:~# kresd --version
Knot Resolver, version 5.7.1
root@turris:~# netstat -anp |grep 0:53
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18768/kresd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*                           18768/kresd
tange@turris:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
search lan
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver ::1
root@turris:/tmp/log# cat /var/log/resolver 
Apr 27 11:52:30 turris kresd[8728]: [system] warning: hard limit for number of file-descriptors is only 4096 but recommended value is 524288
Apr 27 11:52:50 turris kresd[12702]: [system] warning: hard limit for number of file-descriptors is only 4096 but recommended value is 524288


Have you checked your /etc/resolv.conf to ensure your local knot resolver is queried? Have you looked at its logs?

Fixed by:
root@turris:~# /etc/init.d/adblock disable
root@turris:~# reboot

It seems t.co is on an adblock list, and adblock is enabled by default on Turris Omnia.
Edit:
The error came back. Probably due to Turris Omnia auto upgrade. And adblock disable did not fix it.
t.co is listed in: /etc/kresd/adb_list.overall
And removing it here fixed it.
Edit:
It came back.
Removed in /etc/config/resolver:
    list rpz_file '/etc/kresd/adb_list.overall'


Going to the web UI and changing the adblock sources or adding exceptions @ https://192.168.1.1/cgi-bin/luci/admin/services/adblock/whitelist would help.
